# SBT: Create a task say runAll to run main class of all sub modules

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multi-project module like this

```
proj
  |--Module-1
  |  |--src/main/scala
  |        |-- MainClass1.scala
  |--Module-2
  |  |--src/main/scala
  |        |-- MainClass2.scala
  |--build.sbt
```

I want to implement a runAll sbt task so that I can run all main class in different jvm

---

##Note : There can be any number of submodules

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but it may help others who have the same question. Here is my solution.

build.sbt:

```
lazy val runAll = taskKey[Unit]("run-all, for running all main classes")

def runAllIn(config: Configuration) = Def.task {
    val s = streams.value
    val cp = (fullClasspath in config).value
    val r = (runner in run).value
    (discoveredMainClasses in config).value.foreach(c =>
      r.run(c, cp.files, Seq(), s.log))
}

// For the target project that you intend to run "runAll"
lazy val example = (project in file("example"))
  .settings(runAll := runAllIn(Compile).value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best idea would be to call a shell script from your build.sbt task like this

```
val searchPackage = taskKey[Unit]("SearchPackage")
searchPackage := {
  Seq("./run_all_main_class.sh" !)
}
```

You can add all the classes in that shell script, somewhat like this

run_all_main_class.sh would look something like this, you can customize this shell script according to your needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

nohup sbt "runMain com.something.MainClass1" &
nohup sbt "runMain com.something.MainClass2" &
```

Comment: Submodules are not predefined and for adding each module I need to change my .sh files Don't want to do this